# Why am I asked to refactor code and include org.testng.AssertJUnit when creating testng.xml suite?

Tags: java, selenium, testng-eclipse

I have two TestNG classes containing a few `@Test` annotations, nothing fancy,  and test methods just under them. When I select both of my class files in Eclipse, right-click, choose `TestNG - Convert to TestNG`, I am presented with a refacotoring wizard in Eclipse to create said testng.xml suite. But when I cliked Next, I'm asked to refactor my code and include `org.testng.AssertJUnit`.

Why JUnit? What does JUnit have to do with this?

Here's a code sample:

```
package seleniumTestovi.Pages; import org.testng.Assert; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 

public class NewTest { 

@Test 
public void foo() { 
Assert.assertTrue(true); 
  } 
}
```

And here is the code Eclipse wants me to refactor when i try to create `testng.xml` suite.

```
package seleniumTestovi.Pages; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 
import org.testng.AssertJUnit; 
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 
public class NewTest { 

@Test 
public void foo() { 
AssertJUnit.assertTrue(true); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: So... you expect us to guess? You haven't included any code or your XML file.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with my code. But here it is:

`package seleniumTestovi.Pages;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class NewTest {
  @Test
  public void foo() {
   
   Assert.assertTrue(true);
   
  }
}`

Comment: I save it. Right click on that class, chose `TestNG - Convert to TestNG` and Eclipse asks to refactor my code to:

`package seleniumTestovi.Pages;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class NewTest {
  @Test
  public void foo() {
   
   AssertJUnit.assertTrue(true);
   
  }
}
`

Comment: You should always edit your question and post the code there. You want to avoid posting important info in comments. Instead, edit your question, add the important info, and then add a comment stating that you added X or updated your question, etc. That way future readers aren't expected to read all comments to get all the relevant details and can just read the question.